# node server placed behind proxy server failed to GET request to https://localhost:<port>

Tags: node.js, ssl, proxy, squid

On my machine, im hosting a node server that is listening on port 5000. Before setting up a forward proxy (squid), i was able to perform a GET on `https://localhost:<port>`. However, after setting up a forward proxy and setting the environmental variable `http_proxy=<ip addr:port>`, this GET request no longer works.

The error that shows up is: tunnelling socket could not be established, statusCode=503

Some additional information:

- The proxy server works as I am able to connect to the internet via it.
- Performing curl instead, on the https:localhost:5000/api works.
- Am using request.js for the requests, using agentOptions to specify TLS protocols & ca cert.

I am hoping to understand how the traffic is now different after i add in a proxy. From my understanding,  now we have to go through a sort of TLS CONNECT / tunnelling since to the proxy first, since its a HTTPS request, before coming back to my localhost. But in the case without the proxy, how is it that its working?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must add
export no_proxy='localhost,127.0.0.1'
the https work because you don't use proxy for https , you must set https_proxy='<tour_proxy>'

Comment: Hey man thanks! I believe this solved my problem. I was trying to find out more on these environmental variables but couldn't seem to find much info on it. May i know if you know any resources for it/documentation that i can read up on for this? Thanks!